# Terminate EMR Cluster using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, jenkins, aws-sdk, amazon-emr

I have a jenkins job which uses cloud formation template to create EMR.
That EMR performs multiple hive/pig steps. I want to terminate that EMR after the steps are complete, can I do that in the cloud formation template?

I know we can do that using CLI, Console and SDK but is there a provision in CLOUD FORMATION which has the parameter like  KeepJobAliveWhenNoSteps = FALSE?

Comment: I'd too like to know. Did you find anything ? :)

Comment: I did it using Python SDK instead of cloud formation as I did not find any way of doing that. :)

Comment: I myself settled to use the EMR as an object of a Data Pipeline, who terminates automatically once all the steps are run. But the documentation for DataPipeline in CF and the specific syntax are very weak.